# how to reload the view (or just certain variables) after checkbox event

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, checkbox

I have a view with some jQuery functions and nested forms:

```
...
#top part, in the initial form
<div class="checkboxOptions games show-tabs">
  <% @games.each do |game| %>
    <div class="show-tab">
      <div class="checkbox uncheckBoxed">
        <%= check_box_tag "", game.id, @tournament.game_ids.include?(game.id), :onclick => "toggleCheckboxImage(this, '');" %>
      </div>
      <img src="<%= game.logo_url.to_s %>" class="game-logo-label" />
    </div>
  <% end %>
</div> 
...
#'second part' of the form - but in the same view
<div class="tabs">
    <% @tournament.sub_tournaments.each do |sub| %>  
  <% end %>
</div>
...
```

When one of the checkboxes is checked, the second part of the form opens via jQuery and the user continues inputing the necessary information - this all works fine.

The trouble is, some of the variables (`@tournament.sub_tournaments` being the primary example - each game selected becomes a `sub_tournament`) which I need to call in the 'second part' are dependent on which game(s) is/are checked in the 'first part' of the form.  When the page loads, `@tournament.sub_tournaments` is built, but just an empty object.  The page loads successfully, but after a game is checked, I don't have access to the information I need.

**How can I reload the view (or ideally, just a partial) when clicking the checkbox?**

I've been stuck on iterations of this problem for a long time now with varying degrees of (partial) success - but in the end I can't figure out how to reload `@tournament.sub_tournaments` and that's what's really holding me up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the [onchange event](http://api.jquery.com/change/)!

```
jQuery(function() {
  jQuery('#somecheckbox').on('change', function(){
        location.reload();// Resend POST data
        window.location.href=window.location.href; //Doesnt resend POST data
    });
});
```

Also if you need to update the data on your page:

```
jQuery(function() {
  jQuery('#somecheckbox').on('change', function(){
        var _form = '<form id="_myform" action="/*currentURL*/" method="GET" style="display:none;"><input type="text" name="option123" value="'+jQuery(e.target).val()+'" /></form>';
        jQuery('body').append(_form);
        jQuery('#_myform').submit();
    });
});
```

Then get the GET parameter called *option123* via bakcend or front-end and modify your page accordingly.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

in your application.js file:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('#checkbox-id').on('click', function() {

    location.reload();

  });

});
```

That will refresh the page when the checkbox is clicked. (Change #checkbox-id to whatever id you give that checkbox)

Comment: The `onclick` event is not appropriate on a checkbox, the `onchange` event should be used instead...